# Mysql comma separated value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables which looks similar to below table 1 & Table 2.I want out put similar to table 3

```
  Table 1

ParticipantsId | Description | Duration
1,2                 Demo        60 mins
1                   Test        25 mins
1,2,3,4             Alpha       30 mins
4,5,6,2             MCQ         120 mins
```

Table 2

```
UserId |  Name   |  Age
  1       Aku        21
  2       Greg       18
  3       Denver     24
  4       Mike       22
  5       Sid        24
  6       Sriten     19
```

I want the out put to be

Table 3

```
users                   | Description | Duration
Aku,Greg                   Demo          60
Aku                        Test          25
Aku,Greg,Denver,Mike       Alpha         30
Mike,Sid,Sriten,Greg       MCQ           120
```

I have tried find_by_set , group and various other possibilities but I am not able to get the required results, Please help

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated values is the answer. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: @jarlh so no solution for this?

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't touch that mess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `FIND_IN_SET()` together:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(t2.`name`) AS users,
    t1.Description,
    CAST(t1.Duration AS UNSIGNED) AS Duration
FROM
    table1 t1,
    table2 t2
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET(t2.userID, t1.ParticipantsId)
GROUP BY
    t1.Description,
    CAST(t1.Duration AS UNSIGNED)
```

result is:

```
+----------------------+-------------+----------+
| users                | Description | Duration |
+----------------------+-------------+----------+
| Greg,Denver,Aku,Mike | Alpha       |       30 |
| Greg,Aku             | Demo        |       60 |
| Greg,Mike,Sid,Sriten | MCQ         |      120 |
| Aku                  | Test        |       25 |
+----------------------+-------------+----------+
4 rows in set
```

However you must think about normalizing of data structure, comma separated values is a bad practice as someone mentions before.

Comment: This query is against the sql standard and will only run if full group by sql mode is not set. However, it is set by default in the newer versions of mysql.

Comment: @Shadow, totally agree, but there is no way to 'join' these tables using any standard approach.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about the join, I'm talking about the group by :) The join uses mysql functions that solve the problem. However, in the group by you only list description, but not duration.